# issue with wordpress Fatal error: Cannot redeclare frm_dl

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I got this issue with my website using wordpress

I don't know what's the issue, could someone help us out please.

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare frm_dl() (

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can upvote and accept answers if they assisted you in solving your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have duplicate function definitions of the function rm_dl() in wp-settings.php. Please review that file so there is only one definition.

It is also not a good idea to post links to your website and ask "please have a look". Much better and easier for us to help if you post the specific error together with the affected files (without passwords of course!).

If there is nothing wrong with your file the error is most likely caused by some newly installed or updated theme or plugin. In worst case it's some automated hack. In both cases you should reverse to a working backup and make sure you update carefully any plugins and base installations with security updates.

Answer (score -3):

This issue is by cause of virus. It is one type of script when this run this create code in each php file like followuing.
.

the solution is that download your live project file and remove this code and upload again all file on live.
you can replace all that code one time replace all with blank cursor only.

Shiv